# Visual Studio Publish - How to include a folder containing files in the installation?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently trying to publish my application(A C# Application that uses Interop for use with word) on Visual Studio 2017 I'm doing this through the publishing wizard, using the UNC Path option. however my program needs a folder that contains plugins to be installed alongside the program, I can't seem to find a way of doing this so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What kind of app is it? How are you publishing it - e.g., what settings are you choosing? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @JoeSewell I've updated it now, I hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this, all I had to do was modify the csproj file of my application with the following code

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Plugins\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now when I publish my Plugins folder is included, I hope this helps anyone else who gets stuck on the same problem :)